# How to store data unique data in variable for future use using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, session

I have the custom search form in php. when I search any product then product list shows.

I can select any product from the searched product using checkbox. I have a button to add a product in a variable.

Then I am searching again for another product. Now I select a product and click on the button to add product. I have selected 1 value again in new search.

Now I have 2 value. This search can be repeated number of times but the value must be store in a variable and when I am going to the final step then I can use all selected value.

Currently, Value has removed from the variable when searching for new product.

I am using below code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  //var final = '';
// open popup when click on Add Medicine button
  
  var chkArray = [];
  var addedDataArr = [];
  var someVarName;
  $('#addmedicine').click(function(){
    
 
    /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
    $(".checkboxclass:checked").each(function() {
     chkArray.push($(this).attr('datanamemedicne'));
     var textvalue = $(this).attr('mname');
    });

    /* we join the array separated by the comma */
    var selected;
      // selected = someVarName;
    selected = chkArray.join(',') ;
    if(selected.length > 0){
     alert("You have selected " + selected); 
    }else{
     alert("Please at least check one of the checkbox"); 
    }
  });
    
  $("#nextform").click(function(){
   
   $('#c82').val(chkArray);
   $("#transferdetailform").fadeIn();
  });
  $("#cancelpopup").click(function(){
   $("#transferdetailform").fadeOut();
  });
 });
```

```html
<form id="search_doctor_form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $baseURL_l.'reorderform/index/search' ?>" onsubmit="return(valid());" method="get" name="search_form">
 
  <div class="input-box">
  <label for="search">Search</label>
  <input id="search1" type="search" name="search" value="" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="" placeholder="Search here...." />
  <button type="submit" title="Search" class="button search-button" id="btn-search"><span><span>Search</span></span>
  </button>
 </div>
</form>

<ul class="pharmacy-list">

 <li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclass" id="checkboxid" name="medicinecheck[]" value="1" datanamemedicne="Medicine ABC">
  <span id="pharmacy-name-1" class="pharmacy-name" phone="1">Medicine ABC</span> 
  <span id="phamacy-price">500</span>
  <span id="phamacy-image">image here</span>
 </li>
  <li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclass" id="checkboxid" name="medicinecheck[]" value="2" datanamemedicne="Medicine XYZ">
  <span id="pharmacy-name-2" class="pharmacy-name" phone="1">Medicine ABC</span> 
  <span id="phamacy-price">250</span>
  <span id="phamacy-image">image here</span>
 </li>
  

</ul>
<input type="button" name="addmedicine" class="addmedicine" id="addmedicine">Add Medicne</button>
<input type="button" name="nextform" class="nextform" id="nextform">Next Step</button>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried... So that we can help you better

Comment: I have added my code